# SharePoint Calendar event not created when sending a meeting request

Tags: 2007, calendar, incoming-email

I have a calender created on my SharePoint site. I have configured the incoming email settings for the calendar list. I have added an email id for this calendar list.

**When i create a meeting request in outlook, i add the calendar email id in 'To' along with the mail ids of other attendees. But no event is created on the SharePoint calendar.**

What could be the problem.Also. do we need to setup a unique email id for Calender list or any existing ids can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your incoming email is setup correctly?  Can you email a document to an email enabled document library successfully?  I'm unsure what you mean by calendar email id, the way I've gotten this to work in the past was by creating an email address for my events list (incoming email settings on the list) and send the meeting invite to that email address and it showed up in the events list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
In the calendar list settings, under incoming email settings, we have add/setup an email id specific to this list. We have used the mail id of an existing user in AD. But it doesn't seems to work. Do we have create a new email id in Contact(Sync with AD) and then use it?

Comment: Mine doesn't say that.  It says Allow this list to receive email and then below that I create a new email address that represents this calendar.  You shouldn't be using an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other catches that have to do with mail headers that can prevent mail from being received.  Check out [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/some-incoming-emails-being-rejected-on-new-email-enabled-list/51258#51258).

I had the same problem - the emails were getting picked up from the email drop folder, but would never show in the list.  I had to go in the library settings and mark the box "Save original e-mail" for it to show in the list.