# Some incoming emails being rejected on new email-enabled list

Tags: email, discussion-board, exchange-server

I've just set up a new SP list to log purchases made by our department. Whenever we buy something, we'll use the email address corresponding to a distribution group that contains myself and an Exchange contact for a list in SharePoint.

I've set the list to receive mail from any sender and preserve attachments. It's a Discussion list, because I want to keep both the contents and attachments. I tested it from Gmail and it worked as expected.

Now we've purchased some software. This purchase triggered five emails. The SharePoint list only received two of them. Looking in the logs, I have:

> The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators.<nativehr>0x800401e6</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
>
> An error occurred while processing the incoming e-mail file C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\c49c754f01cd766d00000108.eml. The error was: The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators..

To my knowledge, we've never had this issue before with email-enabled lists and we use them rather heavily. Two of the three messages blocked had no file attachments at all and were sent plaintext. All five came from the same source address. If the logs at least told me what file or filetype was being blocked, that might give me somewhere to start, but since it doesn't, and since SharePoint cheerfully tosses the .eml after processing, I don't really have much to go on.

The text of one of the email messages is as follows:

```
x-sender: me@mycompany.com
x-receiver: IT-Purchasing@sharepoint.mycompany.com
Received: from exchange.mydomain.com ([10.0.0.52]) by sharepoint.mycompany.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.17514);
     Fri, 10 Aug 2012 08:44:18 -0400
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.3790.4721
Importance: normal
Priority: normal
Content-class: urn:content-classes:message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Subject: Payment Receipt from Some Vendor
Date: Fri, 10 Aug 2012 08:44:20 -0400
Message-ID: <DD7422A0-7E82-4DFA-B831-57828CFC7DCF@exchange.mydomain.com>
X-MS-Has-Attach: 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
Thread-Topic: Payment Receipt from Some Vendor
Thread-Index: Ac12bhVqmh8qr8JLTkKi80TzqzDBzwAh7wew
From: "Drew Lanclos" <me@mycompany.com>
To: "IT Purchasing" <IT-Purchasing@sharepoint.mycompany.com>
Return-Path: me@mycompany.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 10 Aug 2012 12:44:18.0437 (UTC) FILETIME=[DB722B50:01CD76F5]

KiogUGxlYXNlIGRvIG5vdCByZXBseSB0byB0aGlzIG5vdGlmaWNhdGlvbi4gVGhpcyBtYWlsYm94
---snip---
LS0NClRoZSBBdmFuZ2F0ZSBUZWFtDQpBdmFuZ2F0ZSBJbmMNCmh0dHA6Ly93d3cuYXZhbmdhdGUu
Y29tDQpzdXBwb3J0QGF2YW5nYXRlLmNvbQ0KDQpbW2xjdks1SlhjZ0g0PV1dDQoNCg==
```

Comment: Anything that has to do with outside emails, I set the list to accept all senders in the list settings. How you tried that?

Comment: Yep, paragraph two, first sentence.

Comment: Did you try increasing the logging levels to see if you can get more details?  Can you replicate this both with similar messages and from other domains?  Are the messages encoded the same, MIME must do transfer encoding on  UTF messages when sent, and in some cases can make a message unreadable, even in plain text (and thus flag filters).

Comment: Can you confirm the files are not blocked using blocked file types?

Comment: Do these emails contain files which are on the list of SharePoint's forbidden file extensions in SP-CA? How do you store the attachments?

Comment: @C.Marius - Only one message contained an attachment, and it was a PDF. When SP processes an incoming email, if "Save e-mail attachments" is set to Yes, then the attachments are saved as list item attachments to the first message in a reply chain. It's all OOTB functionality.

Comment: @Russell - See above, only one attachment present, and it was a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I read in [this thread](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2010/08/09/configure-hmailserver-for-sharepoint.aspx) that Sharepoint will only pick up messages that have `x-sender` and `x-receiver` headers.  We use hMailServer, and so are able to script the server to add those headers for Sharepoint-destined messages.

Here is another possibility, from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970818?ppud=4&wa=wsignin1.0):

> For SharePoint 2010
>
> Delivery of e-mail messages is not enabled from SharePoint to other
>   lists within WSS sites. SharePoint filters out e-mail messages when an
>   e-mail message has a destination address of an e-mail-enabled list.
>
> SharePoint checks for the following field in the EML:
>
> X-Mailer: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010
>
> If this field has that value, SharePoint filters that e-mail and does
>   not enable delivery of that e-mail to the list.
>
> Resolution: E-mail messages to SharePoint e-mail enabled lists or document libraries must originate from non-SharePoint senders.

A workaround would be to send the email to another email server and back into Sharepoint - OR edit the mail headers.  There is another workaround-solution [here](https://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=1558).

Yet another thing to look for, having considered your server response, is whether the mime-types are allowed/enabled on your servers iis.  If you lack the mime-type (file type; i.e., extension), the server won't let you do anything at all with the files.

Comment: Well, a good idea, but unfortunately the blocked messages have both `x-sender` and `x-receiver` headers, and they're not sourced from SharePoint. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: I thought of something else - look at the last part of my post.

Comment: I assume you mean the MIME type of the attachments or content, but in this case, it's not a multipart message, just a normal plaintext email. I've included the sanitized content of one of the bounced emails in the question description.

Comment: One thing you could try is to, for awhile, have your email server to copy all the sharepoint-destined incoming mails to another folder, then, you will be able to retain a copy and figure out what was different about the ones that get blocked.

Comment: Could there have been any encryption in the emails?  Even encrypted emails come in plaintext.

Comment: If it was encrypted, I wouldn't know the key, these are just receipts/confirmation messages from software vendors that we have no previous relationship with. And yeah, I got a few .emls out of the folder, I couldn't see anything that jumped out at me as being the culprit.